# How to Access Tag From ID of Different URL jquery

Tags: jquery

Suppose i have file in which it contain

```
<div id='outside'>Hello World</div>
<div id='outside1'>Hello's</div>
```

I have other file using jquery i want to fetch data from above file [az.php] that inside the outside id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#idWhereToLoad').load('az.php #outside, #outside1');
```

#### Loading Page Fragments

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document
>   that is fetched:
>
> 1 $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container'); When this method
>   executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery
>   parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of
>   container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the
>   element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document
>   is discarded, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: No it won't work i'm not able to fetch data of particular id above code. I'm trying to fetch data from different server $('#idWhereToLoad').load('http://serverxx.../az.php #outside, #outside1');
it won't work